Black screen after installing Nvidia drivers on Kubuntu 24.04
My system is a HP820 workstation equipped with a Nvidia Quadro K4000 graphics card.
On a fresh install of Kubuntu 24.04., I experience black screen situation after I installed Nvidia 470 driver by typing the command 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall' and rebooting.
I then choosed the system recovery option from grub start menu and run 'sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*' from the root shell. After reboot, the system works again with the nouveau driver.
How to properly install the Nvidia driver? I did so successfully in the past (Kubuntu 22.04) just with the command 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall' on this system but in Kubuntu 24.04. it seems not working.
Any ideas how to address this problem?
lshw give the following information:
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: GK106GL [Quadro K4000]
       Hersteller: NVIDIA Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:05:00.0
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Version: a1
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       Ressourcen: irq:83 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:a000(Größe=128) memory:c0000-dffff```


Are you using the graphics-drivers PPA? Their driver may work better. New compiler, new kernel, see launchpad bugs 2051457 and 2028165 for some ideas for getting older cards to work.  An older kernel might be needed.

I added the launchpad repository: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu, however it seems when I install the nvidia driver it still chooses the non-PPA one as it is newer?

The newest to me available package of 'nvidia-driver-470' is: 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470 completes without any errors. Just when I then restart I get the black screen. Is there any log files that can be checked (I can boot in recovery mode and reach root shell)?

Look in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/6.8.0-44-generic/x86_64/log/make.log  (your kernel and driver version).

make.log shows: warning: no previous prototype for ‘nvidia_init_module’ [-Wmissing-prototypes] among others. Also it shows warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel    The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0    You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

The differing compilers is the problem, but the error msg seems to indicate they are the same version. My 24.04 Ubuntu Desktop file output is:file /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=6ad55b895026afdd16733e27b925bbf840a37e03, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped  The running kernel compiler may be found by: cat /proc/version

cat /proc/version results for me in:
Linux version 6.8.0-44-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-082) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Aug 13 13:35:26 UTC 2024 Do you have any idea what else I can check? The modules compile fine, its just warnings no errors. Is there a log file showing the things happening on boot, like kernel log file?

Please add requested info into the original posting by editing.  Does turning off secure boot do anything? does modinfo nvidia show information?  Does modprobe successfully add the nvidia module? Check that /etc/modprobe.d files don't black nvidia (only blacklist nvidiafb is OK). I don't have an HP, so search this site for workarounds to several HP issues.
